# client.ApiException: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable) getting error while running java code

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dependencies, connection, application-settings

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfIdu.png)

getting an error as in above image while tring to run application in intellij.
I have one another service running on .default.8080 this is setup properly.
not much I onlie found regarding this issue.
thank you
tried 1. restart 2. unblocking specific ports 3. cache clean up nothing working also not much